# The site that hosted the novelty badges has gone down

Tags: support, badges

Some people created their own novelty badges based on the this post:

> [For those that demand those elusive badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10299/for-those-that-demand-those-elusive-badges)

All that shows is "Alt Text". You may want to go back and remove those badges or replace them with something more sensible.

Comment: That was just a fun question anyway.

Comment: The internet can break? whaaaaat?

Comment: @Olafur: Well, you see, the internet is a series of tubes and these tubes can become clogged...

Comment: @Brad Gilbert - True but I've seen the badges elsewhere so... heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed this myself a while back unfortunately. I ended up just adding alt attributes to all the image tags in the hopes that one day they showed back up.