# Show a badge in my post

Tags: discussion, badges, posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add badges to Markdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100306/add-badges-to-markdown)

Is it possible to show a specific badge in a post or in the profile text?

I know you can show tags like: [python](/questions/tagged/python) or [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), but badges?

---

This is my solution for the moment (an image):

[image]