# Add editor tag [badge:...]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add badges to Markdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100306/add-badges-to-markdown)

We already have editor tag `[tag:]` to insert tags to editted text: [some-tag](/questions/tagged/some-tag)

For some posts here on Meta it would be nice and useful to have editor tag like `[bronze-badge:Benefactor]`
or `[gold-badge:Unsung hero]`, that would draw the badge in the edited text.

Comment: @Mat whoa, ddnt realize this was a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would **not** use `[color-badge:etc...]` but it would be noce to quickly link badges in some way.

Maybe a dropdown or something in the meta editor?