# Badge formatting

Tags: support, badges, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add badges to Markdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100306/add-badges-to-markdown)

Is is possible to display badges with markup similar to the tag formatting?

[legendary](/questions/tagged/legendary) - [ tag : Legendary ]

So something like [badge:Legendary]?