# Inconsistency in privilege pages shown badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges-page, dark-mode

I noticed the following inconsistency in how badges are shown in each privilege page using Dark Mode.

For example:

[**approve tag wiki edits**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)

[image: image of approve tag wiki edits privilege page]

[**vote up**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

[image: image of vote up privilege page]

From my research this hasn't been reported before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We do [not have any way to render badges in Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100306/add-badges-to-markdown) which means we also cannot render them in help center articles either. Because of that, these were all just screenshots of the badges inserted as images in the article.

I have replaced them all with plain text in the help center. Replacing the images all the time is tedious and I am a devout supporter of removing unnecessary images that add no value to the article from support documentation.

Comment: Taking this opportunity to point out one more detail, badge names in the privilege pages are mostly written in bold but in the [set bounty privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) are written in regular font.

Comment: @bad_coder Updated. :)