# How can I embed badges into my profile?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page

I want to showcase my rarest badges on a site in my profile. For example:

[image: badges]

How do I do this?

Comment: Well, you just did?

Comment: @rene That was made with the "Inspect" function and copying the span style for badges.

Comment: Screenshot it?.

Comment: @Zoethe1337Princess I'm assuming that you are asking if I got my image from a screenshot; the answer to that is **yes, I took a screenshot of an "inspected" page**

Comment: No, that was a suggestion. Just screenshot the badge and paste it on your profile

Comment: Very closely related (perhaps even a duplicate): [Add badges to Markdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100306/348196)

Comment: Also, doesn't your profile already [highlights the rarest badges](https://i.imgur.com/qeo123h.png) anyway?

Comment: Your profile already lists your rarest badges. You could otherwise just _name_ the badges you earned; I do this in my profile on Stack Overflow (I name the badges where I was the first account to earn them).

Comment: @41686d6564 Yeah, but I want people to see the badges just on my profile page instead of having to scroll down to see my badges.

Comment: @fasterthanlight What Martijn is that you can manually type the name of the badges (check their SO profile). Or you could use screenshots as others have suggested. If neither of those solutions is good enough, your best bet would be the linked feature request. It got a [status-declined] since 2016 but could be revised at some point as the accepted answer states.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment, this function is unavailable. See [Add badges to Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100306/add-badges-to-markdown) for more details.

However, that was 9 years ago and **I would like this ability as well**.

I understand that it wouldn't have too many benefits, but I mainly support it as I think it would just make life a little bit easier. This way I could easily check out the badge's description and I could view others with the badge without manually finding the badge.

The embedded badge function would definitely make life easier, but it would probably make the SE Team's life a lot harder though, so I anticipate that this potential function will remain stalled.

For now, simply use a screenshot to "show off" your new badge.

Comment: I suspect part of it might be an unwillingness to extend markdown for the main site past the vaguely standard markdown of the past and today's commonmark

Comment: Clickable tags are already a thing using `[tag:foobar]` [tag:foobar], something similar could be done with badges. It's a bit more involved and probably won't have the rarity (bronze/silver/gold) associated with it, so it could be a lot of work for little gain.

Comment: @Mast Yep, which is why I said " it would probably make the SE Team's life a lot harder though".